# Node js program refusing to execute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been running a program for over a year on my raspberry pi using node js. recently is has started to throw error whenever I try to run the main aspect of the code which is to post on reddit, send messages etc. It gives me this error:

```
 node /home/pi/redditbots/redditbot/index.js[1003]: ../src/spawn_sync.cc:466:void node::SyncProcessRunner::TryInitializeAndRunLoop(v8::Local<v8::Value>): Assertion `(uv_loop_init(uv_loop_)) == (0)' failed.
```

when I try to do anything within the program. I have done research on what this error means but have come up dry.

Comment: As a guess, I'd say the reddit API changed or perhaps this has some token issued it uses for posting but the token has expired. Hard to say without knowing what it's actually trying to do.

Comment: @vlaz I don't believe it is a problem with the Reddit api because it sometimes lets me post. could it be an issue with node itself?

Comment: Again, it's hard to say without knowing what it's actually trying to do when it fails.

Comment: @vlaz That's an assertion error in the V8 runtime, barely has anything to do with the JS code or the reddit API.

Comment: @Bergi how could I fix it?

Comment: @cdoern I'd say [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/spawn_sync.cc#L70) should never happen, and you found a bug in node.js. Try to make a [mcve], probably centered around some `spawn` call in your program, and report the issue at the nodejs github repo.